# How to take user input and convert to the needed type use generic type class?

Tags: java, generics, user-input

I am new to java and I am trying to use a generic type class to take user input and convert it to different types(including Integer, String, Bigdecimal) in different situations. I have got 3 questions here.

1. Can I check if a class field member with generic type is an instance of for example String or not if you set the T as String when declaring the class object.
2. If I can test 1, are there ways that I can assign String value to the field member with generic type?
3. Is it possible to convert the user input into different types according to the T that set when declare, for example, if the T is set to be Integer then the class method will know that I need to use Integer.parseInt(user input) to convert this and then store it into class field member?

Can anyone give a solution or some hint to the above questions?

Below is my code. If this approach is impossible, is there any ways that I can get this job done?

```
public class userInputReader<T> {

    private T userInput;

    public userInputReader()throws IOException
    {
        readUserInput();
    }


    private void readUserInput() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader userInputBReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        if(userInput instanceof String)
        {
            userInput = userInputBReader.readLine();
        }
        else if(userInput instanceof Integer)
        {
            userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInputBReader.readLine());
        }
        else if(userInput instanceof BigDecimal)
        {
            userInput = new BigDecimal(userInputBReader.readLine());
        }

    }
}
```

I am new here and if anything I have done has breached the rules here please kindly point it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that there is a difference between what you see in the source code and what you'd see in the compiled output.

Using the above code means writing

```
final UserInputReader<String> reader = new UserInputReader<>();
```

And that's it. It's fine *outside* that class, you can see that instance works with a `String` type.
However *inside* that class, it's a bit different.

The problem is in Java generic types' information is erased during compilation, so after compilation, the `UserInputReader` will look like

```
public class UserInputReader {
    private Object userInput;
    ...
```

> Can I check if a class field member with generic type is an instance
>   of for example String or not if you set the T as String when declaring
>   the class object.

Sure, you can, but that's totally independent from using a generic type or not.

> If I can test 1, are there ways that I can assign String value to the
>   field member with generic type?

As you saw in my example above, the class field will just become

```
private Object userInput;
```

So yes, you can assign whatever you want to an `Object`, it's the mother of all.

> Is it possible to convert the user input into different types
>   according to the T that set when declare, for example, if the T is set
>   to be Integer then the class method will know that I need to use
>   Integer.parseInt(user input) to convert this and then store it into
>   class field member?

You already did this, using the `instanceof` operator.

**However**, being that `userInput` is `null` until you assign it, you cannot compare its type in any meaningfull way.

Those checks

```
if (userInput instanceof String)
else if (userInput instanceof Integer)
else if (userInput instanceof BigDecimal)
```

will always yield `false` at that point. What you're doing is basically

```
if (null instanceof String)
```

---

The only possible approach, if you still want to decide at construction point which type of object you'll deal with, is passing to the constructor the `Class<?>` type.

```
public class UserInputReader {
    private final Class<?> clazz;
    private Object userInput;

    public userInputReader(final Class<?> clazz) throws IOException {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        readUserInput();
    }

    ...
```

For example

```
final UserInputReader reader = new UserInputReader(String.class);
```

Which can than be used like

```
if (String.isAssignableFrom(this.clazz)) {
   userInput = userInputBReader.readLine();
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering in great detail. With the above answer can I just conclude that I can just rewrite the class field "T userInput" to Object type, and ignore the thought of generic class and use a normal class?

Comment: @Jimmy added more context. Check it out

Comment: Thanks for your update, and sorry I didn't make myself clear enough. I mean, I'll just pass the type I want to deal with as a String argument when I construct the class and adjust the methods to check that argument instead of checking T. And sorry my knowledge of java is quite limited. I have got this problem with generic type with my own code above, my editor is popping errors which say "Incompatible types, Required: T, Found: String" when I try to assign string or other types of value to userInput. Is this sth that can be solved with the above updated solution you have given? Thx !

Comment: @Jimmy updated with the easiest solution. You can basically use my code.
You don't have to pass a string like "new UserInputReader("string"), but "UserInputReader(String.class)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking, that you may want to go with something like:

```
    public void userInputReader(Class<T> tClass) throws IOException
    {
        readUserInput(tClass.newInstance());
    }

    private void readUserInput(T t) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader userInputBReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        if(t instanceof String)
        ...
```

This should allow you to test for the type of the generic field. I believe that you already have the answers to your other two questions then.